# Why is the graph of the linear regression incorrect? Code and image provided

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

I was doing a linear regression using `statsmodels` in Python, and when I plotted the result it appeared erroneous. I checked a different data set, using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068862/how-to-overplot-a-line-on-a-scatter-plot-in-python/19069001#19069001).

But even when I use the following code (taken from the above linked question), the line of best fit is still not displayed correctly. I am unsure what the problem is.

Code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(100)
Y = X + np.random.rand(100)*0.1

results = sm.OLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X)).fit()

print results.summary()

plt.scatter(X,Y)

X_plot = np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(X_plot, X_plot*results.params[0] + results.params[1])

plt.show()
```

My output:

[image: Bad Linear Regression]

Why isn't the line of best fit correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_constant` prepends the constant by default, which means that the constant is the first parameter and the slopes are the following parameters.

The predicted values are also available as `fittedvalues` or by calling predict without arguments.

For the explicit calculation the indices of `params` need to be corrected, i.e.

`predicted = X_plot*results.params[1] + results.params[0]`