# python binning: how to increase the range

Tags: python

I got a scatter graph of Volume(x-axis) against Price(dMidP,y-axis) scatter plot, and I want to divide the x-axis into 30 evenly spaced sections **for the entire range** and average the values, then plot the average value I.e. the red dots
[image]

however, if bin = 30: the plot only covers a small range of x
[image: bin=30]

then I increase bin to 100 (the line is less smooth
[image]

then to 500:
[image]

do you know why is the x range changing?

------------------update-----------------------------------------

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : np.log(TradeNa['Volume']), 'Y' : TradeNa['dMidP']}) 
data_cut = pd.cut(df.X, np.linspace(df.X.min(), df.X.max(), 30))          #we cut the data following the bins
grp = df.groupby(by = data_cut)        #we group the data by the cut

ret = grp.aggregate(np.mean)         #we produce an aggregate representation (median) of each bin

plt.loglog(np.log(TradeNa['Volume']),TradeNa['dMidP'],'o')
plt.loglog(ret.X,ret.Y,'r-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in your questions. Specify which library you're using.

Comment: done, thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.cut(df.X,bins)` splits your data into roughly equal chunks.

I think for what you want, you need to do `pd.cut(df.X, np.linspace(df.X.min(), df.X.max(), 30))` instead.

Comment: Please do elaborate.

Comment: thanks for your reply. please see the update of the question

Comment: I see what you mean now, if you want the cut in the log space then you need to take the logs in the arguments of the `np.linspace`. So something like `pd.cut(df.X, np.linspace(np.log10(df.X.min()), np.log10(df.X.max()), 30))`.

Comment: thanks, but this code gives me an error saying that 'Bin edges must be unique:  e: array([        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,  1.81016713]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg'

Comment: Your `df.X.min()` less than 0, that's why it failed. (It also means you should not plot things like that in log scale)  You can "fix" this by shifting your X column or clipping it, but I am not sure if it's reasonable in the context of your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102343/edit-binning-data-scatter-plot-in-python for the update of the question

Comment: Hi Ryan, may I ask how can you shift the X column?

Comment: `df['X'] = df['X'] + df['X'].min() + 1` to offsetthe column such that the new minimum is 1.