# Drawing a line through points; matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

For my graph, I have constructed a series of points like so

```
 for x in range (0,9):
     plt.scatter(r[x],functions[x],color='green')
```

where r[x] and functions[x] are both arrays with 9 elements.

The scatter plot works fine; however, I was wondering if there was anyway I could draw a line instead of just some points. Or if I can draw a line through the points.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a line connecting the points? In that case you can just do: `plt.plot(r,functions,color='green')` if `r` and `functions` contain more than 9 elements use: `r[:9]` and `functions[:9]`.

Answer (score -1):

This might help: [How to overplot a line on a scatter plot in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068862/how-to-overplot-a-line-on-a-scatter-plot-in-python)

In case you are trying to plot a regression line through the points, which is a different case, maybe this would help: http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0170/

(I would've commented but I don't meet minimum reputation requirements. Hope I helped!)