# Linear regression example using matplotlib instead of pylab

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

Since pylab is discouraged, I intend to use matplotlib from this example in https://www.wired.com/2011/01/linear-regression-with-pylab/

```
from pylab import *

x = [0.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.9, 3.3]
y = [3.3, 3.9, 4.8, 5.5, 6.9]

(m, b) = polyfit(x, y, 1)
print(m, b)

yp = polyval([m, b], x)
plt.plot(x, yp)
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(x,y)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

If I start this one with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I don't know how to replace polyfit and polyval functions in matplotlib. In line 4 and 7, these call the polyfit and polyval function (those are in the pylab module). What functions should I use instead for using matplotlib?

I want to use this example but using matplotlib.

Comment: Please don’t paste images of your code. Include the actual code so people trying to help you don’t have to transcribe your image.

Comment: You are right. The site actually has the image, I'll try typing the code next time.

Comment: FYI, you can edit questions and type the code yourself. @MarkMeyer was nice enough to use his own time to do it this time.

Comment: As requested, it is done. Thank you. @mark-meyer

Comment: It looks good @RakibulHassan -- I didn't downvote this, but if I had I would undo it.

Comment: @mark-meyer I don't mind about downvoting it. You responded properly what I really wanted. Much appreciated for what you have done. I didn't expect you would would type it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`polyfit` and `polyval` are both available in `numpy`. So you can simple use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.9, 3.3]
y = [3.3, 3.9, 4.8, 5.5, 6.9]

(m, b) = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
print(m, b)

yp = np.polyval([m, b], x)
plt.plot(x, yp)
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Outstanding! As you said, polyfit and polyval are both available in numpy, we could go ahead and use it. Meanwhile, I was planning to use `import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.9, 3.3]
y = [3.3, 3.9, 4.8, 5.5, 6.9]`  to plot and add the best fit line. What could be the best way to plot both with less code? Thank you once again @mark-meyer

Comment: Can this be done with Seaborn's regplot or lmplot as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40478505 ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. I thought I accepted both the answers. It seems that, you can only accept one. I didn't want to hurt anyone.

Answer (score 2):

The plotting functions are in `matplotlib.pyplot` but PyLab also includes numerical functions from NumPy which you can with

```
import numpy as np

np.polyfit(...)  # etc.
```

(See also the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot).)