# How to annotate multiple lines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Multiple Lines]

```
plt.plot(np.arange(1000), np.arange(1000), label = "y = x")
plt.plot(np.arange(1000), 2*np.arange(1000), label = "y = 2x")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How can I modify it to write the labels on the line instead on the legend?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780198/how-to-rotate-matplotlib-annotation-to-match-a-line?sa=X&ved=0CBYQ9QEwAGoVChMIu_Cku8SAxwIVSQUsCh2ulAB7